# Are dimensioned variables only re-dimensioned if you give it an initial value?

Tags: .net

I just ran across some behavior that I wouldn't have expected in .NET:

```
Dim switch = True
Dim items = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}

For Each item In items
    Dim someId As Integer

    If switch Then
        switch = False

        someId = 123
    End If

    Console.WriteLine("Item: {0}, SomeId: {1}", item, someId)
Next
```

The output of the code is:

```
Item: 1, SomeId: 123
Item: 2, SomeId: 123
Item: 3, SomeId: 123
Item: 4, SomeId: 123
Item: 5, SomeId: 123
Item: 6, SomeId: 123
```

Whereas I would have expected:

```
Item: 1, SomeId: 123
Item: 2, SomeId: 0
Item: 3, SomeId: 0
Item: 4, SomeId: 0
Item: 5, SomeId: 0
Item: 6, SomeId: 0
```

So are variables only re-dimensioned if you give a default value? Where can I find some documentation of this behavior?

Edit: I guess I'm most confused by the fact that I'm in a loop, so I would think that the expected result would be that I would want a newly allocated integer for **someId**.

Comment: Put the `Dim someId` outside of the loop and see how it changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by design In VB.NET, a variable that is declared inside of a `For` loop keeps its value for each subsequent loop iteration.

So you set the value of `someId` to 123 on the first iteration, and it maintains that value. The `someId` variable is *not* reinitialized on each subsequent loop.

The exact same thing happens if you declare `someId` outside of the loop, e.g.

```
Dim switch = True
Dim items = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}

Dim someId As Integer
For Each item In items

    If switch Then
        switch = False

        someId = 123
    End If

    Console.WriteLine("Item: {0}, SomeId: {1}", item, someId)
Next
```

…but I would say that then the behavior would be expected. The rationale is the same, though. In both cases, the `someId` variable has *block scope*, so its value persists.

You said you want some documentation for this behavior. In the section on [scope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t0wsc67.aspx), it says:

> Even if the scope of a variable is limited to a block, its lifetime is still that of the entire procedure. If you enter the block more than once during the procedure, each block variable retains its previous value. To avoid unexpected results in such a case, it is wise to initialize block variables at the beginning of the block.

To generate the output you want, you will have to modify the code to explicitly reinitialize `someId`:

```
Dim switch = True
Dim items = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}

Dim someId As Integer
For Each item In items

    If switch Then
        switch = False

        someId = 123
    Else
        someId = 0
    End If

    Console.WriteLine("Item: {0}, SomeId: {1}", item, someId)
Next
```

But whatever you do, **please, please give your variables a type**!